# Primefaces DataTable sort issue

Tags: jsf, sorting, primefaces, datatable

I have problem in a datatable. All columns have sortBy on header, except the last one that has a TieredMenu and each MenuItem calls to backing bean using item as parameter.
Datatable is loaded with a List ordered by one field, I am not using a DataModel.

The problem is that after order by any field the item passed as parameter is the initial and not the actual.

For example:

initially list is ordered by third field:

```
gomez 5 4
alvarez 3 5
carballo 3 8
```

after order by first field:

```
alvarez 3 5
carballo 3 8
gomez 5 4
```

If I click on first row I get gomez instead of alvarez.

This is the code for the datatable:

```
<p:dataTable scrollable="true" scrollHeight="290" 
        value="#{bb.list}"
        id="tablaEnAtencion" var="item" width="100%" rows="10000"
        sortBy="#{item.third}" sortOrder="descending"
        filteredValue="#{bb.listFiltered}">
    ...
    <p:column style="text-align:center;" width="24">
        <p:commandButton id="dynaButtonAtencion" icon="ui-icon-gear" type="button" style="width:100%;" />
        ...
        <p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButtonAtencion" my="left top" at="left bottom" style="width:170px">
            <p:menuitem value="action" actionListener="#{bb.act1(item)}" />
        </p:tieredMenu>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In the project I have a lot of DataTable and this issue only happens on this table.
I've tried:
- remove sort on some columns
- adding sort event without listener
- adding sort event with sort listener and on this method order by code the list
- remove filter
- use f:setPropertyActionListener to send values to bb

Backing bean is ViewScoped.
Primefaces 3.4, faces 2.1.13.

Comment: I've found the problem. The page has a tabView with 2 tabs: the first one has 2 dataTable (the second one has the problem) and the second tab has a dataTable. After add rendered atribute to panel that contains table on second tab problem is not happening anymore.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet to your solution? I am stuck in the same problem, but am unable to understand your explanation. Thanks a ton!